# Python complex event processing

Tags: python, complex-event-processing

Are there any Python alternatives similar to [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) (Java and .NET) that deal with complex event processing (CEP)?

Answer (score 4):

Casual browsing indicates that this is not a very common problem domain for Python (although very interesting!). The framework that closest come to my mind is [PEAK-Rules](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PEAK-Rules) or [dynrules](http://www.sysfault.org/dokuwiki/projects:dynrules).

There might be more, but not widely known (I'll search a bit more)

For your own digging: the place to find Python projects is first and foremost [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/).

(@cues7a: Twisted, while indeed being an event framework, is too low-level to be comparable to Esper.)

**Edit:** It seems you can control Sybase's [CEP products with Python](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01030.0400/doc/html/swa1260999284692.html)

Answer (score 3):

The ruleCore CEP Server uses dynamically loaded Python modules which can be used to extend it. The internal architecture is build around a central event bus which uses a pub/sub approach. So each module can subscribe to internal events and publish events based on logic inside the module.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kaskada project](https://kaskada.io/) isn't exactly a CEP tool, but it has some similarities to CEP systems and provides a Python client designed for notebook environments like Jupyter.

For example, you can query for things like "how many pageviews have occurred since the last time a user made a purchase":

```
PageView | count(window=since(Purchase))
```

Kaskada's query language is based on the idea of a timeline, and many of the operations provided by CEP languages (followed-by, repeated, etc) have analogs in Kaskada's query language.

*Disclaimer*: I am a contributor to the Kaskada project.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Twisted Matrix](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)?